# Plotly : How to make group and stack bar subplots in one figure?

Tags: pandas, plotly

Below is the working sample code that populate 3 subplots. I am trying to show 1st subplot as 'group'(row=1,col=1) and remaining two subplots as 'stack'. I have also selected the 'barmode' for each subplot. But my final figure has all 'stack' subplots.  I have referred few forum and they suggested to use 'offset' for each subplot but even that parameter is not working out. Please suggest.
Note: In real-time, all subplots are based on different dataframes but I took only one dataframe for this post.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go


#creating my dataframe
s = 200
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country": np.random.choice(["USA America", "JPY one two", "MEX", "IND", 
  "AUS"], s),
   "economy_cat": np.random.choice(["developing","develop"], s),
   "gdp": np.random.randint(5, 75, s),
   })
#filter dataframe for one country
df = df[df.Country=='USA America']
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='Country',columns='economy_cat',values='gdp',aggfunc='sum')
df_pivot.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df_pivot)

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=4)
# creation of subplots 1
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
       x=df_pivot["Country"],
       y=df_pivot["develop"],
       marker_color = '#1f77b4', 
       name='develop'
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1,
 )
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
    x=df_pivot["Country"],
    y=df_pivot["developing"],
    marker_color = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)",
    name='developing'
   ),
    row=1,
    col=1,
)
 fig.update_layout(barmode = 'group')
# creation of subplots 2
 fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df_pivot["Country"],
       y=df_pivot["develop"],
       marker_color = '#1f77b4', 
        name='develop'
    ),
     row=1,
     col=2,
 )
fig.add_trace(
go.Bar(
    x=df_pivot["Country"],
    y=df_pivot["developing"],
    marker_color = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)",
    name='developing'
),
row=1,
col=2,
  )
fig.update_layout(barmode = 'stack')
# creation of subplots 3
fig.add_trace(
go.Bar(
    x=df_pivot["Country"],
    y=df_pivot["develop"],
    marker_color = '#1f77b4', 
    name='develop'
  ),
  row=2,
  col=1,
 )
   fig.add_trace(
   go.Bar(
    x=df_pivot["Country"],
    y=df_pivot["developing"],
    marker_color = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)",
    name='developing'
     ),
     row=2,
     col=1,
     )
fig.update_layout(barmode = 'stack')

fig.update_layout(
    font_family="Droid Sans")
```

Comment: Any suggestions from anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternating between `fig.update_layout(barmode = 'stack')` and `fig.update_layout(barmode = 'group')` won't help you because this parameter modifies the entire figure, including each subplot, which is why they all behave the same way.

According to [this helpful article](https://dev.to/fronkan/different-barmodes-simultaneously-in-a-plotly-subplot-python-1efc) by Frederik Bengtsson, you can use the `offsetgroup` parameter.

To get two bars to *group* together in a subplot when you add them as individual traces, you can set `offsetgroup=0` for the first trace and `offsetgroup=1` for the second trace.

And to get two bars to *stack* in a subplot, you can set offsetgroup=0 for both traces, but set the `base` parameter of the second trace to be the y-values of the first trace.

I modified your code slightly to include multiple countries to illustrate stacked and grouped bars:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go


#creating my dataframe
s = 200
df = pd.DataFrame({"Country": np.random.choice(["USA America", "JPY one two", "MEX", "IND", 
  "AUS"], s),
   "economy_cat": np.random.choice(["developing","develop"], s),
   "gdp": np.random.randint(5, 75, s),
   })
#filter dataframe for one country
# df = df[df.Country=='USA America']
df_pivot = df.pivot_table(index='Country',columns='economy_cat',values='gdp',aggfunc='sum')
df_pivot.reset_index(inplace=True)
print(df_pivot)

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=2)
# creation of subplots 1 - grouped
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
       x=df_pivot["Country"],
       y=df_pivot["develop"],
       offsetgroup=0,
       marker_color = '#1f77b4', 
       name='develop'
    ),
    row=1,
    col=1,
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
    x=df_pivot["Country"],
    y=df_pivot["developing"],
    offsetgroup=1,
    marker_color = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)",
    name='developing'
   ),
    row=1,
    col=1,
)
# fig.update_layout(barmode = 'group')
# creation of subplots 2 - stacked
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df_pivot["Country"],
        y=df_pivot["develop"],
        offsetgroup=0,
        marker_color = '#1f77b4', 
        name='develop'
    ),
    row=1,
    col=2,
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df_pivot["Country"],
        y=df_pivot["developing"],
        offsetgroup=0,
        base=df_pivot["develop"],
        marker_color = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)",
        name='developing'
    ),
    row=1,
    col=2,
)
# fig.update_layout(barmode = 'stack')
# creation of subplots 3 - stacked
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
        x=df_pivot["Country"],
        y=df_pivot["develop"],
        offsetgroup=0,
        marker_color = '#1f77b4', 
        name='develop'
      ),
    row=2,
    col=1,
)
fig.add_trace(
    go.Bar(
    x=df_pivot["Country"],
    y=df_pivot["developing"],
    offsetgroup=0,
    base=df_pivot["develop"],
    marker_color = "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)",
    name='developing'
    ),
    row=2,
    col=1,
)
# fig.update_layout(barmode = 'stack')
fig.update_layout(font_family="Droid Sans")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply. In actual, my each subplots are based on different dataframes. So, is this logic valid for different dataframes. Because here, we are setting the base paramater based on same dataframe. Please suggest.

Comment: Yes, this method will work as long as you use the same DataFrame values within the same subplot.